# resizing window/div causes div to flicker

Tags: jquery, resize, easing

I'm pretty sure that I should be using easing for this problem, but not certain how to implement it.

I have the following code:

```
function resizeBlock() {
    if ($("#blocks").width < 995) {
    $blwidth = 0;
    }
    else {
    $blwidth = ($("#blocks").width());
    $blwidth = ($blwidth + 60) - 990;
    $("#block-left").width($blwidth);
    }
};
$(window).resize(function(){
resizeBlock();
}
```

The div #block-left flickers/jumps when resizing the window. How would I use easing to fix this?

MTIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [jQuery Animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

$("#block-left").animate({
    width: $blwidth
  });

Comment: Thanks, but how do I use animate to change the width using the var $blwidth?